# Uncaught ReferenceError: method not defined

Tags: javascript

So i've been working on a project but it keeps throwing errors no matter what I've tried. Below is the javascript I've been using inside the head tag.

```
<script>
        //True is x, false is o
        var turn;

        //declare and initialize variables
        function start()
        {
            alert("before");

            turn = true;

            cells = new Array([document.getElementById("cell00"), document.getElementById("cell01"), document.getElementById("cell02")],[document.getElementById("cell10"), document.getElementById("cell11"), document.getElementById("cell12")],[document.getElementById("cell20"), document.getElementById("cell21"), document.getElementById("cell22")]);

            alert("after");
            turnChange();
            alert("complete");
        }

        /**
        create the function that will check, each time a cell is clicked, if the move is legal and will, if it is not legal, display an alert if the move is illegal, it should also check to see if this move is a winner, i.e., call checkWinner()
        */
        function doClick(row, col)
        {
            var xOrO;
            if(turn)
                xOrO = "X";
            else
                xOrO = "O";

            if(cells[row][col].innerHTML.length == 0){
                cells[row][col].innerHTML = xOrO;
                turn = !turn;
            } else
                alert("This space is already taken");
            checkWinner();

        }
/**
        This function runs after every turn and displays which player's turn it is
        */
        function turnChange()
        {
            var temp;
            if(turn)
                temp = "Player 1 (X)";
            else
                temp = "Player 2 (O)";

            document.getElementById("playerTurn").innerHTML = temp;
        }

        /**
        create function to check if the last move made makes this a win
        display winning message if it is a winner
        */
        function checkWinner()
        {
            var xWin = false;
            var yWin = false;

            if(var x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                if(cells[i][0]);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                for (var j= 0; j < 3; j++){
                    if ()
                    win = false;
                }
            }

            if (win) {
                alert("Congratulations! You won!");
                id (window.prompt("Play again?", "yes"));
                placeNumbers();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

The error however crops up at my onload or onclick in the body of the code. The onload has stopped throwing errors for me, but it still refuses to run the code.

```
<body>
    <div id="container" onload="start()">
        <h1 id="logo"><em>Tic Tac Toe</em></h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="content">
            <p><input type="button" value = "Restart the game" id = "restartButton" onclick = "start()"/></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

All of the above was in html tags, and all of them have the appropriate end tags. Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

The error thrown is 
Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (TTT.html:94)
The alerts that are listed in my start method also do not run, which leads me to believe that the method itself is ignored.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (TTT.html:94)

Comment: `div` element doesn't have an `onload` event

Comment: I just changed it over, a new error was thrown Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined
    at onload (TTT.html:89)

Comment: something is not letting your script to be evaluated. What does the head look like?

Comment: My head only contains the script tags, which surround my javascript, a link to my css file and the heads opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

`turnChange` is not defined which is where your error is coming from. I also moved `onload` attribute to the body element so it will work as expected.

`checkWinner` function also appears to not be defined, but your code is erroring before it gets to that call anyway.

```js
//True is x, false is o
var turn;

//declare and initialize variables
function start() {
  alert("before");

  turn = true;


  //all cells below will be null
  cells = new Array([document.getElementById("cell00"), document.getElementById("cell01"), document.getElementById("cell02")], [document.getElementById("cell10"), document.getElementById("cell11"), document.getElementById("cell12")], [document.getElementById("cell20"), document.getElementById("cell21"), document.getElementById("cell22")]);

  alert("after");
  turnChange(); //this function is undefined - root of problem
  alert("complete");
}

function doClick(row, col) {
  var xOrO;
  if (turn)
    xOrO = "X";
  else
    xOrO = "O";

  if (cells[row][col].innerHTML.length == 0) {
    cells[row][col].innerHTML = xOrO;
    turn = !turn;
  } else
    alert("This space is already taken");
  checkWinner(); //this doesnt appear to be defined either
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
  <!-- moved onload to body element -->
  <div id="container">
    <h1 id="logo"><em>Tic Tac Toe</em></h1>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="content">
      <p><input type="button" value="Restart the game" id="restartButton" onclick="start()" /></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved the onload method but It caused another error. The other methods were previously in my code, I just didn't have them listed on the question.